MasmBasic assembly code to encrypt any file problem
I had problem with line 15
test.asm(15) : error A2008: syntax error : ,
the code
include \masm32\MasmBasic\MasmBasic.inc   
.data
    key db "AMU", 0
    keyLength db 3,0

Init

Let esi = Input$("Enter the filename: ", "test.txt")  
Let edi = FileRead$(esi)   
Let eax = LastFileSize      
Let ebx = 0                 


For_ ebx = 0 To eax - 1
    xor [edi + ebx], ByteAt(key, ebx % keyLength)   
Next


Let esi = Left$(esi, Rinstr(esi, ".")) + "xyz"


FileWrite esi, edi, LastFileSize   

EndOfCode


I'm noob with MasmBasic lib
I don't know if there is ByteAt or how to use it
I use
ml.exe /c /coff test.asm

and got
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.15.8803
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-2000.  All rights reserved.
Assembling: test.asm
*** MasmBasic version 28.04.2024 ***

Warning: SQWORD is unsigned with this assembler *
test.asm(15) : error A2008: syntax error : ,


There does not seem to be a ByteAt. Also xor does not take two memory operands. I don't know masmbasic but maybe you can do let edx = ebx % keyLength; mov dl, [key + edx]; xor [edi + ebx], dl

What happens if you write xor byte ptr [edi + ebx], Chr$("AMU", ebx % 3)

i got that error
test.asm(15) : error A2070: invalid instruction operands
test.asm(14) : error A2206: missing operator in expression
Chr$(107): Macro Called From
test.asm(14): Main Line Code
